# error report message explained

Tags: error, reports, debug

When getting an error page, there is always a line at the beginning of the file, that states where the error happened, for example:

`a:5:{i:0;s:172:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in path/to/the/file/Sales/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice.php, line 1";i:1;s:1539:"`

or

`a:5:{i:0;s:25:"No date part in '' found.";i:1;s:6372:"#0 path/to/the/file/code/core/Zend/Date.php(1091): Zend_Date->_calculate('set', false, NULL, 'en_US')`

What exactly do these `i:0;s:25`, `i:0;s:172:`, `i:1;s:6372`, `i:1;s:1539:`,  parts mean?

Comment: put  Invoice.php code

Comment: this question is not meant to search for an answer for those particular errors. I would like to know what those i and s statements mean, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i:0;s:25, i:0;s:172:, i:1;s:6372, i:1;s:1539:
```

The error message along with other information it being serialized by the error handler so you see what would be a php array/object in it's serialized form.

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) will give you more details on how serialize works.

Answer (score 0):

user3432078,you have `echo or print or var_dump` at Invoice.php `Just remove echo or print and var_dump`

Comment: thanks, for your help, but the error messages was just an example. I updated the question to make it more clear.